# How do you verify an RSA SHA1 signature in Python?

Tags: python, cryptography, rsa, sha1, signature

I've got a string, a signature, and a public key, and I want to verify the signature on the string. The key looks like this:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDfG4IuFO2h/LdDNmonwGNw5srW
nUEWzoBrPRF1NM8LqpOMD45FAPtZ1NmPtHGo0BAS1UsyJEGXx0NPJ8Gw1z+huLrl
XnAVX5B4ec6cJfKKmpL/l94WhP2v8F3OGWrnaEX1mLMoxe124Pcfamt0SPCGkeal
VvXw13PLINE/YptjkQIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

I've been reading the pycrypto docs for a while, but I can't figure out how to make an RSAobj with this kind of key. If you know PHP, I'm trying to do the following:

```
openssl_verify($data, $signature, $public_key, OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA1);
```

Also, if I'm confused about any terminology, please let me know.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The data between the markers is the base64 encoding of the ASN.1 DER-encoding of a PKCS#8 PublicKeyInfo containing an PKCS#1 RSAPublicKey.

That is a lot of standards, and you will be best served with using a crypto-library to decode it (such as M2Crypto as [suggested by joeforker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/544433/how-do-you-verify-an-rsa-sha1-signature-in-python/546043#546043)). Treat the following as some fun info about the format:

If you want to, you can decode it like this:

Base64-decode the string:

```
30819f300d06092a864886f70d010101050003818d0030818902818100df1b822e14eda1fcb74336
6a27c06370e6cad69d4116ce806b3d117534cf0baa938c0f8e4500fb59d4d98fb471a8d01012d54b
32244197c7434f27c1b0d73fa1b8bae55e70155f907879ce9c25f28a9a92ff97de1684fdaff05dce
196ae76845f598b328c5ed76e0f71f6a6b7448f08691e6a556f5f0d773cb20d13f629b6391020301
0001
```

This is the DER-encoding of:

```
   0 30  159: SEQUENCE {
   3 30   13:   SEQUENCE {
   5 06    9:     OBJECT IDENTIFIER rsaEncryption (1 2 840 113549 1 1 1)
  16 05    0:     NULL
            :     }
  18 03  141:   BIT STRING 0 unused bits, encapsulates {
  22 30  137:       SEQUENCE {
  25 02  129:         INTEGER
            :           00 DF 1B 82 2E 14 ED A1 FC B7 43 36 6A 27 C0 63
            :           70 E6 CA D6 9D 41 16 CE 80 6B 3D 11 75 34 CF 0B
            :           AA 93 8C 0F 8E 45 00 FB 59 D4 D9 8F B4 71 A8 D0
            :           10 12 D5 4B 32 24 41 97 C7 43 4F 27 C1 B0 D7 3F
            :           A1 B8 BA E5 5E 70 15 5F 90 78 79 CE 9C 25 F2 8A
            :           9A 92 FF 97 DE 16 84 FD AF F0 5D CE 19 6A E7 68
            :           45 F5 98 B3 28 C5 ED 76 E0 F7 1F 6A 6B 74 48 F0
            :           86 91 E6 A5 56 F5 F0 D7 73 CB 20 D1 3F 62 9B 63
            :           91
 157 02    3:         INTEGER 65537
            :         }
            :       }
            :   }
```

For a 1024 bit RSA key, you can treat `"30819f300d06092a864886f70d010101050003818d00308189028181"` as a constant header, followed by a 00-byte, followed by the 128 bytes of the RSA modulus. After that 95% of the time you will get `0203010001`, which signifies a RSA public exponent of 0x10001 = 65537.

You can use those two values as `n` and `e` in a tuple to construct a RSAobj.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I spent quite some some time chasing standards docs but never found all the pieces. The "fun info" is definitely appreciated.

Answer (score 31):

Use [M2Crypto](http://www.heikkitoivonen.net/m2crypto/api/M2Crypto.X509-module.html). Here's how to verify for RSA and any other algorithm supported by OpenSSL:

```
pem = """-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDfG4IuFO2h/LdDNmonwGNw5srW
nUEWzoBrPRF1NM8LqpOMD45FAPtZ1NmPtHGo0BAS1UsyJEGXx0NPJ8Gw1z+huLrl
XnAVX5B4ec6cJfKKmpL/l94WhP2v8F3OGWrnaEX1mLMoxe124Pcfamt0SPCGkeal
VvXw13PLINE/YptjkQIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----""" # your example key

from M2Crypto import BIO, RSA, EVP
bio = BIO.MemoryBuffer(pem)
rsa = RSA.load_pub_key_bio(bio)
pubkey = EVP.PKey()
pubkey.assign_rsa(rsa)

# if you need a different digest than the default 'sha1':
pubkey.reset_context(md='sha1')
pubkey.verify_init()
pubkey.verify_update('test  message')
assert pubkey.verify_final(signature) == 1
```

Comment: PHP's openssl_verify calls exactly the same functions as the above Python code.

Comment: Thanks joe. If I could mark two as the answer I'd mark yours too.

Comment: Arg, I've been trying to get this to work for a while, but I keep just getting -1 from the verify_final. The values I have verify correctly using PHP.

Comment: If you corrupt your message do you get a different return code from verify_final? Does your message have any special characters that might be encoded differently in Python? Are you using the latest M2Crypto? See also http://svn.osafoundation.org/m2crypto/trunk/tests/

Comment: No, no, and "whatever apt gets". I'll try those tests before checking for a newer version. Here are the PHP and Python versions, in case I'm doing anything obviously wrong: http://pastebin.com/f58e6809a http://pastebin.com/f137244e1 . Thanks again.

Comment: @Andrew So you know which files to look for, the example above mostly uses the EVP API (test_evp.py). You could also try making RSA-specific "verify" calls (test_rsa.py). If you get desperate, compare with http://cvs.php.net/viewvc.cgi/php-src/ext/openssl/openssl.c?view=markup

Comment: @Andrew: did you find out what was the difference between the PHP and Python version? I do have the same exact problem as you.

Comment: @Sylvain No, I actually don't think I ever did. If someone posts working code I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 3):

A public key contains both a modulus(very long number, can be 1024bit, 2058bit, 4096bit) and a public key exponent(much smaller number, usually equals one more than a two to some power). You need to find out how to split up that public key into the two components before you can do anything with it.

I don't know much about pycrypto but to verify a signature, take the hash of the string. Now we must decrypt the signature. Read up on [modular exponentiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation); the formula to decrypt a signature is `message^public exponent % modulus`. The last step is to check if the hash you made and the decrypted signature you got are the same.

Answer (score 1):

<del>I think [ezPyCrypto](http://www.freenet.org.nz/ezPyCrypto) might make this a little easier. The high-level methods of the **key** class includes these two methods which I hope will solve your problem:</del>

- <del>[verifyString](http://www.freenet.org.nz/ezPyCrypto/detail/public/ezPyCrypto.key-class.html#verifyString) - verify a string against a signature</del>
- <del>[importKey](http://www.freenet.org.nz/ezPyCrypto/detail/public/ezPyCrypto.key-class.html#importKey) - import public key (and possibly private key too)</del>

[Rasmus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5542/rasmus-faber) points out in the comments that `verifyString` is hard-coded to use MD5, in which case ezPyCryto can't help Andrew unless he wades into its code. I defer to [joeforker's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/544433/how-do-you-verify-an-rsa-sha1-signature-in-python/546476#546476): consider [M2Crypto](http://www.heikkitoivonen.net/m2crypto/api/M2Crypto.X509-module.html).

Comment: Taking a quick look at this, it seems like verifyString() is hardcoded to use MD5 and that importKey uses a homemade, non-standard format. So unfortunately, I don't think he will be able to use this.

Answer (score 1):

More on the DER decoding.

DER encoding always follows a TLV triplet format: (Tag, Length, Value)

- Tag specifies the type (i.e. data structure) of the value
- Length specifies the number of byte this value field occupies
- Value is the actual value which could be another triplet

Tag basically tells how to interpret the bytes data in the Value field. ANS.1 does have a type system, e.g. 0x02 means integer, 0x30 means sequence (an ordered collection of one or more other type instances)

Length presentation has a special logic:

- If the length < 127, the L field only uses one byte and coded as the
  length number value directly
- If the length > 127, then in the first byte of L field, the first bit
  must be 1, and the rest 7 bits represents the number of following
  bytes used to specifies the length of the Value field.   Value, the
  actually bytes of the value itself.

For example, say I want to encode a number of 256 bytes long, then it would be like this

```
02  82  01  00  1F  2F  3F  4F  …   DE  AD  BE  EF
```

- Tag, 0x02 means it's a number
- Length, 0x82, bit presentation of it is 1000 0010, meaning the
  following two bytes specifies the actually length of the value, which
  his 0x0100 meaning the value field is 256 bytes long
- Value, from 1F to EF, the actual 256 bytes.

Now looking at your example

```
30819f300d06092a864886f70d010101050003818d0030818902818100df1b822e14eda1fcb74336
6a27c06370e6cad69d4116ce806b3d117534cf0baa938c0f8e4500fb59d4d98fb471a8d01012d54b
32244197c7434f27c1b0d73fa1b8bae55e70155f907879ce9c25f28a9a92ff97de1684fdaff05dce
196ae76845f598b328c5ed76e0f71f6a6b7448f08691e6a556f5f0d773cb20d13f629b6391020301
0001
```

It interprets as just what Rasmus Faber put in his reply

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this isn't the answer you're looking for, but if all you need is to turn the key into bits, it looks like it's Base64 encoded. Look at the `codecs` module (I think) in the standard Python library.

Comment: The only way I can find to create an RSAobj requires a tuple as input.

Answer (score 0):

Using M2Crypto, the above answers does not work. Here is a tested example.

```
import base64
import hashlib
import M2Crypto as m2

# detach the signature from the message if it's required in it (useful for url encoded data)
message_without_sign = message.split("&SIGN=")[0]
# decode base64 the signature
binary_signature = base64.b64decode(signature)
# create a pubkey object with the public key stored in a separate file
pubkey = m2.RSA.load_pub_key(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'pubkey.pem'))
# verify the key
assert pubkey.check_key(), 'Key Verification Failed'
# digest the message
sha1_hash = hashlib.sha1(message_without_sign).digest()
# and verify the signature
assert pubkey.verify(data=sha1_hash, signature=binary_signature), 'Certificate Verification Failed'
```

And that's about it

Answer (score -1):

I try the code given by joeforker but it does not work.
Here is my example code and it works fine.

```
from Crypto.Signature import PKCS1_v1_5
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA 
from Crypto.Hash import SHA

pem = """-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDfG4IuFO2h/LdDNmonwGNw5srW
nUEWzoBrPRF1NM8LqpOMD45FAPtZ1NmPtHGo0BAS1UsyJEGXx0NPJ8Gw1z+huLrl
XnAVX5B4ec6cJfKKmpL/l94WhP2v8F3OGWrnaEX1mLMoxe124Pcfamt0SPCGkeal
VvXw13PLINE/YptjkQIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----""" # your example key

key = RSA.importKey(pem)
h = SHA.new(self.populateSignStr(params))
verifier = PKCS1_v1_5.new(key)
if verifier.verify(h, signature):
  print "verified"
else:
  print "not verified"
```

Comment: what does it means self.populateSignStr?