# BER decode error when loading key

Tags: c++, rsa, digital-signature, crypto++

I've been working on digital signer and verifier using Crypto++. I ancountered the following problem: my signer and verifier work well on the public and private keys I generated programmatically using the first example (Generate an RSA keypair and save it) from this [wiki](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/User_Guide:_rsa.h). But when I use another test key pair I was provided to test, I have the following error: "BER decode error" when trying to load key for signing. I've been searching the Internet, but can not manage to solve the problem. Here are my classes:

```
class DSUtility
{
protected:
    DSUtility() = default;
    template<typename KeyType, typename KeySourceType>
    KeyType PrepareKey_(const std::string& key_source);     
};

template<typename KeyType, typename KeySourceType>
KeyType DSUtility::PrepareKey_(const std::string& key_source)
{
    CryptoPP::ByteQueue key_bytes;
    KeySourceType(key_source.c_str(), true, new CryptoPP::Base64Decoder).TransferTo(key_bytes);
    key_bytes.MessageEnd();
    KeyType key;
    key.Load(key_bytes); // FAILS WHEN TRYING TO SIGN WITH ANOTHER PRIVATE KEY
    return key;
}


class Signer : private DSUtility
{
public:     
    Signer(const std::string& private_key);

    std::string Sign(const std::string& data);

private:
    typedef CryptoPP::RSA::PrivateKey PrivateKey;
    CryptoPP::RSASS<CryptoPP::PKCS1v15, CryptoPP::SHA256>::Signer signer_;
};


Signer::Signer(const std::string& private_key) :
signer_(PrepareKey_<PrivateKey, CryptoPP::StringSource>(private_key))
{
}

std::string Signer::Sign(const std::string& data)
{
    CryptoPP::SecByteBlock signature(signer_.SignatureLength());
    signer_.SignMessage(CryptoPP::AutoSeededRandomPool(), (byte const*)data.c_str(), data.size(), signature);
    return std::string(signature.begin(), signature.end());
}
```

one of my keys (that works) looks like this:

```
MIICdgIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCAmAwggJcAgEAAoGBAILkZnFV77ckeZkepDk1fvsE
qli05im29PTZq0ayWZsSgis+tpzP2KpSigWimAfkOCF36Y1Zb9E8VcxBaRbEEH0ObQTQdOl0
z1Cf0mViD2dQgH+8ZucU2gKy0YDpjIJ6wZM55azNZBg1s5J9PuDyM+nMRh5RiJqEpaXSXzgV...
```

another one looks the following:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIICXAIBAAKBgQDGwB5n/xMsDoqo+bGaws15FYGGjsJxCM2deHJZqV2QKfvkmStf
8HntPqaJ+mc9UA6ghN1uGndChg1PuHSNVaRU2x8fem/mFUhfOJaZcYich8JAy0nm
sJUOwoRqLfKjLWmqy0QZHXDDVw+sD5uq/oOvfFFjuYIcsskHQmGTfkdJrQIDAQAB...
```

Comment: Have you tried removing that obviously different `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----` line?

Comment: Yes, I did that at the first step:)

Answer (score 2):

> But when I use another test key pair I was provided to test, I have the following error: "BER decode error" when trying to load key for signing.

Its hard to say what's going wrong... You should provide ***real*** test keys. Its not worth the time to try and decode a fake on with "..." in it because we know it will fail.

I'm just guessing, but it might be a raw key (i.e., just the public or private key, without the identifier) rather than a key info (i.e., the outer sequence and identifier with the inner public or private key). The latter (the key info) is sometimes called a ***`subjectPublicKeyIdnfo`*** when its a public key.

You might want to take a look at [Keys and Formats](http://cryptopp.com/wiki/Keys_and_Formats) on the Crypto++ wiki. The guide you cited is kind of old, and its provided for historical purposes. Here's the 3-second tour:

- When you load a ***`raw key`***, call `BERDecode`
- When you load a ***`key info`***, call `Load`
- When you save a ***`raw key`***, call `DEREecode`
- When you save a ***`key info`***, call `Save`

---

> ```
> template<typename KeyType, typename KeySourceType> KeyType 
> DSUtility::PrepareKey_(const std::string& key_source)
> {
>     CryptoPP::ByteQueue key_bytes;
>     KeySourceType(key_source.c_str(), true, new CryptoPP::Base64Decoder).TransferTo(key_bytes);
>     key_bytes.MessageEnd();
>     KeyType key;
>     key.Load(key_bytes); // FAILS WHEN TRYING TO SIGN WITH ANOTHER PRIVATE KEY
>     return key;
> }
> ```

This can probably be simplified a bit:

```
template<typename KeyType, typename KeySourceType> KeyType 
DSUtility::PrepareKey_(const std::string& key_source)
{
    ArraySource as((const byte*)key_source.data(), key_source.size(),
                                true, new Base64Decoder());
    key.Load(as);
    return key;
}
```

And if its a ***`raw key`***, you might try:

```
key.BERDecode(as);
```

---

> *"... another one looks the following: `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`..."*

For the PEM encoded keys, see [PEM Pack](https://cryptopp.com/wiki/Pem_Pack) on the Crypto++ wiki.

Here's a reference to a Stack Overflow question, but it just cites the Crypto++ wiki page (in addition to other answers): [Load PEM encoded private RSA key in Crypto++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9815001).

---

> FAILS WHEN TRYING TO SIGN WITH ANOTHER PRIVATE KEY

Also, "fails when trying to sign another private key" is different than "fails when trying to load". I tried to stay focused on the question you asked, so it may not be the answer you were hoping for.

After you spend some time on Stack Overflow, you might grow weary of people who answer the question they hoped it would be ***rather than*** the question that was actually asked. I got tired of it very quickly, so I attempt to stay very focused when answering (its the reason I cite everything I answer, even if its a comment).