# How to verify in pycrypto signature created by openssl?

Tags: python, openssl, python-2.x, pycrypto

I've created private/public key in openssl, and signed some data:

```
openssl genrsa -out private.pem 1024
openssl rsa -in private.pem -out public.pem -outform PEM -pubout
echo 'data to sign' > data.txt
openssl dgst -md5 < data.txt > hash
openssl rsautl -sign -inkey private.pem -keyform PEM -in hash  > signature
```

now in python, I'm trying to verify this data:

```python
pubKey = open('public.pem').read()
data = open('data.txt').read()
signature = open('signature').read()

from Crypto import PublicKey
key = PublicKey.RSA.importKey(pubKey)
pub = key.publickey()
hash = MD5.new(data).hexdigest()
# here, hash is same, as contents of 'hash' file
print pub.verify(hash, signature) # <-- here
```

the problem is, that `pub.verify` expects second parameter to be one-element list with some large number. And I don't know how to convert binary data in file `signature` to this integer. Every example about pycrypto shows signature generated *from* pycrypto, and `key.sign()` generates correct signature in form `(1832273432...2340234L, )`. But I dont know how to use external signature.

If this is necessary, below are additional informations, which I don't exactly know how to interpret:

Brief technical information:

- Format of digital signature: PKCS#7 “Signed-Data”
- Public key procedure: DSS
- Key length: 512 – 1024 bits
- Public exponent:  2 +1
- Public key format: X.509 v3 certificate
- MD (Message Digest) algorithm: MD5 or RIPEMD-160 16

Answer (score 8):

The [Crypto.Signature](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/api/current/Crypto.Signature-module.html) module is what you want. From the `Crypto.Signature.PKCS1_v1_5` documentation:

```py
key = RSA.importKey(open('pubkey.der').read())
h = SHA.new(message)
verifier = PKCS1_v1_5.new(key)
if verifier.verify(h, signature):
   print "The signature is authentic."
else:
   print "The signature is not authentic."
```

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem and here are examples for both, generating and verifying with openssl and python. Hope this helps someone...

Bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Generate keys
openssl genrsa -out priv.pem
# Export public key
openssl rsa -pubout -in priv.pem -out pub.pem
# Create test file
echo test123 > test.txt
# Create SHA1 signature
openssl dgst -sha1 -sign priv.pem -out test.txt.sig test.txt
# Verify SHA1 signature
openssl dgst -sha1 -verify pub.pem -signature test.txt.sig test.txt
```

Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from Crypto.Signature import PKCS1_v1_5
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Hash import SHA
from Crypto import Random
# Read public key from file
fd = open('pub.pem', 'r')
key_data = fd.read()
fd.close()
# Load public key
key = RSA.importKey(key_data)
# Read test file
fd = open('test.txt', 'r')
message = fd.read()
fd.close()
# Create SHA1 hash object
h = SHA.new(message)
# Create PKCS1 handler
cipher = PKCS1_v1_5.new(key)
# Read signature file
fd = open('test.txt.sig', 'r')
signature = fd.read()
fd.close()
# Verify signature
print cipher.verify(h, signature)
# Read private key from file
fd = open('priv.pem', 'r')
priv_key_data = fd.read()
fd.close()
# Load private key
priv_key = RSA.importKey(priv_key_data)
# Create PKCS1 handler
priv_cipher = PKCS1_v1_5.new(priv_key)
# Sign hash of test file content and compare
signature2 = priv_cipher.sign(h)
if signature == signature2:
    print "Match!! :)"
```

After some more reading i've learned (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS_1) that PKCS1_PSS is the new scheme that should be used to create signatures.

Both scripts needs some changes:

Bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Generate keys
openssl genrsa -out priv.pem
# Export public key
openssl rsa -pubout -in priv.pem -out pub.pem
# Create test file
echo test123 > test.txt
# Create SHA1 signature
openssl dgst -sha1 -sigopt rsa_padding_mode:pss -sigopt rsa_pss_saltlen:-1 -sign priv.pem -out test.txt.sig test.txt
# Verify SHA1 signature
openssl dgst -sha1 -sigopt rsa_padding_mode:pss -sigopt rsa_pss_saltlen:-1 -verify pub.pem -signature test.txt.sig test.txt
```

Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from Crypto.Signature import PKCS1_PSS
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Hash import SHA
from Crypto import Random
# Read public key from file
fd = open('pub.pem', 'r')
key_data = fd.read()
fd.close()
# Load public key
key = RSA.importKey(key_data)
# Read test file
fd = open('test.txt', 'r')
message = fd.read()
fd.close()
# Create SHA1 hash object
h = SHA.new(message)
# Create PKCS1 handler
cipher = PKCS1_PSS.new(key)
# Read signature file
fd = open('test.txt.sig', 'r')
signature = fd.read()
fd.close()
# Verify signature
print cipher.verify(h, signature)
# Read private key from file
fd = open('priv.pem', 'r')
priv_key_data = fd.read()
fd.close()
# Load private key
priv_key = RSA.importKey(priv_key_data)
# Create PKCS1 handler
priv_cipher = PKCS1_PSS.new(priv_key)
# Sign hash of test file content and compare
signature2 = priv_cipher.sign(h)
# PKCS1_PSS signatures always differ!
#if signature == signature2:
#    print "Match!! :)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution.

```
from Crypto.Util import number
signature  = number.bytes_to_long(signature) #Convert the signature to long
print pub.verify(hash, (signature,) ) #Pass tuple to verify
```

Comment: Apparently this way dont work - returns False. I've tried this way http://pastebin.com/uPtrwngm as you suggested

Answer (score -1):

This post gives you the best answer.
[How do you verify an RSA SHA1 signature in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/544433/how-do-you-verify-an-rsa-sha1-signature-in-python)

pycrypto could not verify a signature created by OpenSSL. You may try M2Crypto.